# Python generator how does it close a file handle when the for loop calling the generator returns suddenly?

Tags: python

If the function `lookForSpecificLine` returns `True` (aka, if the file "foo.txt" contains the `targetLine`), how does Python know to close the file handle? Would the file "foo.txt" remain open?

```
def lines(filename):
    with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        for line in file:
            yield line

def lookForSpecificLine(targetLine):
    for line in lines('foo.txt'):
        if targetLine == line:
            return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your file will remain open as long as the generator object is alive. When the generator is garbage collected (at the end of the `lookForSpecificLine` function, usually), Python will call `close` on it, as part of the co-routine protocol described in  [PEP 342](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/). The `close` method causes Python to throw a `GeneratorExit` exception into the generator's code at the place it was paused (just after the `yield` statement). Since you don't catch that exception (as you usually shouldn't), it will break out of the loop and cause the `with` statement to close the file.

Note that if `lookForSpecificLine` was more complicated and there was some risk of it causing an exception (that would be caught at a higher level), things might not get cleaned up quickly. That's because the exception traceback will keep the function's stack frame alive, and so the generator will not be garbage collected immediately and the file will not be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This works because file objects are also context managers.  Basically a class needs to define an `__enter__` and an `__exit__` function which will be called at the start and end of the `with` block respectively.

Here is a simple example of a context manager which prints "on enter" at the start of the `with` block and "on exit" at the end:

```
class contextmanager:
    def __enter__(self):
        print('on enter')
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        print('on exit')
```

and an example using it:

```
>>> with contextmanager():
...     print('inside with')
...
on enter
inside with
on exit
```

Now lets try it with an Exception being raised inside the with statement:

```
>>> with contextmanager():
...     raise Exception()
...
on enter
on exit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
Exception
```

You can see that the code inside the `__exit__` function gets called at the end of the `with` statement whether it executed normally or raised an Exception.  In the case of file objects, they use this function to close file handles and clean up.

Comment: When the for-loop returns True early, how does the for-loop tell the file object inside the generator to call its __exit__ function?

Comment: the `with` statement is equivalent to a try/finally with `__exit__` called inside the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

The file is closed after you leave the `with` block. See e.g. [PEP343](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) and [this guide](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm) for more info on the `with` statement.